# Google picker make a copy when uploading

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I have replicated the [google file picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) in a web app.

My question is how would I tell the google picker to **make a copy** of the file when uploading it to google drive ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that google picker could not do what I needed so Google App Script to the rescue.

- Firstly you need to create a new google spreadsheet
- Under "Tools->Script Editor" add the following code

Thought trial an error I came up with the following.

```
function copyFiles() {

   var dApp = DriveApp; // Get the drive app
   var folderIter = dApp.getFoldersByName('parentFolder'); //Get folder my id
   var folder = folderIter.next(); // Get the first folder
   var fileIter = folder.getFiles(); // File iterator

   var storageFolder = folder.getFoldersByName('childFolder').next(); // Get target folder
   var subFolderIter = storageFolder.getFiles(); // sub folder File iterator

   while(fileIter.hasNext()) { 

      var file = fileIter.next();  // Get the current File
      var fileName = file.getName();

     // Check if the current file exists in a coped folder
     // If false make a copy  else do noting
     // This check prevents duplicate, Becasue makeCopy generates uniques ID everytime
     if(!storageFolder.getFilesByName(fileName).hasNext()) {
         //Logger.log('Files does NOT exists');
        file.makeCopy(storageFolder);
     } else {
      //Logger.log('Files does exists');
     }

   }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who might need.

Note: You will need to set up triggers for the script to run when required